# Case assignment with custom button

Tags: custom-button, assignment-rules

I have a field on the Case object which when updated to true needs to trigger the assignment rule.
It seems that an inline edit does not trigger the rules so I think of writing a custom detail page button which updates a field in my case, and I need the case assignment rules to be evaluated as a result of this record update. 
What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger for this.  See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187821&language=en_US) for a sample on how to do this.